# SoapUI: Setting test-suite property from any place of project

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm using soapui free vers.

I can set test-suite level property from any test-case in this suite with

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("testSuiteProp",somevalue)
```

But I have some test-suites. And want to set properties for each test-suite, but from one groovy script(inside one test-case).

So, question: how to set test-suite property with groovy from other test-suite in groovy script?

Comment: and same question for getting values: how to get property value for certain test-suite, from groovy script in other test-suite?

Answer (score 4):

> //To set at suite level

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue( "LastTuesday", "Holiday");
```

> //to set other suite from current suite

```
def myTestSuite = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite 2")
myTestSuite.setPropertyValue( "Stackoverflow", "awesome");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set same property to every testsuite, you can use the following snippet in your groovy script.

```
def testSuites = context.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteList()
testSuites.each{
it.setPropertyValue("name","value");
}
```