# SOAPUI: How to pass context property back and forth between calling and called groovy script test steps

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm using SoapUI and I have the following project structure:

Project

- TestSuite1

  - testCase1

    - **groovy script 1** test step.  Calls groovy script 2 using the following code:

```
context.variable = "String set in groovy script 1"
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("MyTestSuite").getTestCaseByName("MyCalledTestCase").run(new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap(context),false)

log.info('from calling script: ' + context.newVariable);
```

- TestSuite2

  - testCase2

    - **groovy script 2**.  Called by groovy script 1.  This code looks like this:

```
log.info('from context: ' + context.variable);
context.newVariable = 'set in groovy script 2';
```

When I run **groovy script 1** I get

```
Wed Sept 04 16:13:59 BST 2023:INFO:from context: String set in groovy script 1
Wed Sep 04 16:13:59 BST 2023:INFO:from calling script: null
```

How can I return the value of **context.newVariable** to **groovy script 1**?

Comment: I used this to set properties in the calling testSuite
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454490/soapui-setting-test-suite-property-from-any-place-of-project